# How to copy dll file dependency to Temp compilation folder for Azure Function App?

Tags: c#, xml, azure, dll

I am working with an azure function app that uses a third-party DLL, that has a dependency on an XML mapping file being present in a folder relative to the current execution. When I publish and run my function on my Azure stack, I run into an exception that the dll cannot load the XML file.  I have the XML present in my bin directory with the dll, but Azure appears to be moving the compiled dlls to a temporary folder without the required XML, and proceeds to be looking for the XML relative to that temporary path based on the following exception message:

```
"Could not find a part of the path 'D:\\local\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\da2a6178\\25f43073\\assembly\\dl3\\28a13679\\d3614284_4078d301\\Resources\\RepresentationSystem.xml'."
```

Is there any way I can make sure these additional files are also copied to the temporary folder that Azure is running?  Alternatively, can I just force it to run from bin rather than temp?

Update:  Unfortunately I am not permitted to share any info on the dll.  What I can say is that everything is published to my wwwroot folder, however when outputing some debug info, I can see that the execution is happening from the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder.  Each dll is copied to its own seperate folder. D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\da2a6178\25f43073\assembly\dl3\28a13679\d3614284_4078d301\ThirdParty.dll is that path were the dll in question is, and it lines up with where it expects the xml to be.

Comment: Using [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/), you could find that your resource files are under `D:\home\site\wwwroot`. And your function execution directory is not the same as the content directory you deployed to azure. And it would look like `D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.11388\`. I would recommend you update your question and provide more details about your third-party DLL for us to locate that how it read the xml file. If it is possible, you could use the absolute path for reading the xml file.

Comment: You could leverage [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy-------) to check the code for reading xml file within the third-party DLL by yourself to narrow this issue. Moreover, does your azure function work as expected locally?

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a true answer to the issue, a workaround for this problem was to have a function in code before the dll functions run, that searches for the dll in question in the Temp ASP.Net folder, and then copies the xml files from a known location to that directory.

```
// Work Around Begin Here
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
// Check if we are in temp dir
if (assemblyFolder.Contains("Temporary ASP.NET Files"))
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(assemblyFolder);
    // Go up 2 dirs
    DirectoryInfo top = dir.Parent.Parent;
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = top.GetDirectories();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo child in dirs)
    {
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs2 = child.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo child2 in dirs2)
        {
            // Find out if this is the Rep
            if (File.Exists(child2.FullName + "\\ThirdParty.Representation.dll"))
            {

                // Look to see if resource folder is there
                if (!Directory.Exists(child2.FullName + "\\Resources"))
                {
                        child2.CreateSubdirectory("Resources");
                }

                DirectoryInfo resDir = new DirectoryInfo(child2.FullName + "\\Resources");

                if (File.Exists(resourceDir + "RepresentationSystem.xml"))
                {
                    if(!File.Exists(resDir.FullName + "\\RepresentationSystem.xml"))
                    {

                        File.Copy(resourceDir + "RepresentationSystem.xml", resDir.FullName + "\\RepresentationSystem.xml");
                    }
                }

                if (File.Exists(resourceDir + "UnitSystem.xml"))
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(resDir.FullName + "\\UnitSystem.xml"))
                    {

                        File.Copy(resourceDir + "UnitSystem.xml", resDir.FullName + "\\UnitSystem.xml");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DoubleHolo for this workaround. It run fine.
I have changed the code adding only **Path.Combine** to simplify the code.

```
private void CopyResourcesToTemporaryFolder()
{
        // Work Around Begin Here
        string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string resourceDir = Path.Combine(FileUtils.WebProjectFolder, "Resources");

        // Check if we are in temp dir
        if (assemblyFolder.Contains("Temporary ASP.NET Files"))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(assemblyFolder);
            // Go up 2 dirs
            DirectoryInfo top = dir.Parent.Parent;
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = top.GetDirectories();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo child in dirs)
            {
                DirectoryInfo[] dirs2 = child.GetDirectories();
                foreach (DirectoryInfo child2 in dirs2)
                {
                    // Find out if this is the Rep
                    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(child2.FullName, "AgGateway.ADAPT.Representation.DLL")))
                    {

                        // Look to see if resource folder is there
                        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(child2.FullName, "Resources")))
                        {
                            child2.CreateSubdirectory("Resources");
                        }

                        DirectoryInfo resDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(child2.FullName, "Resources"));

                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(resourceDir, "RepresentationSystem.xml")))
                        {
                            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(resDir.FullName, "RepresentationSystem.xml")))
                            {

                                File.Copy(Path.Combine(resourceDir, "RepresentationSystem.xml"), Path.Combine(resDir.FullName, "RepresentationSystem.xml"));
                            }
                        }

                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(resourceDir, "UnitSystem.xml")))
                        {
                            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(resDir.FullName, "UnitSystem.xml")))
                            {

                                File.Copy(Path.Combine(resourceDir, "UnitSystem.xml"), Path.Combine(resDir.FullName, "UnitSystem.xml"));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```